# Validate PassportJS via Callback or Mongoose Model?

Tags: node.js, validation, mongoose, passport.js

I am setting up passport for the sign up and login user authentication. Now I saw that I can validate the information via the callback, however I could also validate the information in the User model. For example, if I want to make the email field required, then I can do the following:

**Validation with Passport**

```
// Create the local sign up with Passport
passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField : 'userEmail', // Email Field
    passwordField : 'userPassword', // Password Field
    passReqToCallback : true
    },
    function(req, email, password, done) {

        // Find a user with this email
        User.findOne({ "local.email": email }, function(err, user) {

            if (err) throw err;

            // If a user with this email already exists, continue with failureRedirect
            if (user) {
                return done(null);

            } else {
                // Otherwise create a new user with the email and generate a hashed password
                User.create({
                    local: {
                        email: email
                    }
                }, function(err, user) {
                    if (err) throw err;

                    user.local.password = user.generateHash(password);

                    // Return the user and finish! :)
                    return done(null, user);
                });
            }
        });
    };
}));
```

**With the User Model**

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    local: {
        email: {
            type: String,
            unique: true // Make it unique! Handles entire validation
        },
        password: {
            type: String
        },
    }
});
```

Which of them is recommended and why?

Answer (score 1):

Why not both? If you use the second one only, it will be difficult to show the message

> email address already exists

as you need to catch the `duplicate key error index` and then display the error message at signup. Instead of that you could check that if email address already exists which is more explicit and display the corresponding error message at signup at the same time using unique index will make sure that there are no duplicate entries for email address.

Comment: Good point. Do you know any best practices when it comes to validations in express or authentication?

Comment: I am relatively a newbie myself to MEAN stack. But so far I have been using the middleware provided by defualt like auth.requiresLogin. To validate a single request you can use req.isAuthenticated(). But I haven't created my custom authorizations yet. Maybe you can create access levels and use them as middlewares to authorize levels of data. I am not sure that is the standard practice. Maybe someone with more experience will give us more insight

Comment: I have a bit of a Rails background so I am used to the [Active Record Validations](http://waa.ai/43zn). I am not using the MEAN stack, but I wrote an **isLoggedIn** function for the routes, so that checks whether a user is authenticated or not.

I am more concerned about validations, such as __minimum characters, maximum characters, regex, uniqueness, presence, etc__.

Writing them into the passport callback file is quite messy in my opinion, especially, if the user wants to make changes to his/her information. The validations would need to be rewritten into the controller, which isn't DRY

Comment: I assume you are using mongoose. You can define [custom validation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html) for Schema types which act as middleware themselves. But be aware of the fact that the middleware(validation) isn't called when using the `.update()`.

Comment: If you think that my answer has solved your problem, please feel free to mark it as an accepted answer.